# Google Docs crash

Tags: google, htc, htc-one, documents

I have non rooted HTC One M8 (Android 6.0)
When I try editing document in Google docs aplication, it crashes (more like minimization). That happen every time after I press any letter under document.
I tried:
1) deleting cache 
2) rebooting phone
3) changing keyboard (current is Swift)

Can someone help me?
Many thanks!

Comment: Try updating app

Comment: I have latest version

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the exact same problem the past month or so, and in looking for solutions I just found the app CCleaner could cause it. Just removed the CCleaner app and Docs works perfectly! Same problem for you perhaps?